# Error using getImageFromFile (line 11)

Tags: matlab

My code execute correctly for the digits but it given some errors to the characters. the image presented in that location but it shows image not found like..

```
Error using getImageFromFile (line 11)
Cannot find the specified file: "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\vision\visiondemos\characters\handwritten\B\img012-00012".

Error in imageDisplayParseInputs (line 73)
[common_args.CData,common_args.Map] = ...

Error in imshow (line 219)
[common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in charmodified (line 22)
subplot(2,3,4); imshow(testChar{1,2});
```

Comment: Maybe the file-extension (e.g. jpeg, png, gif, ...) is missing? The Windows explorer hides known file-extensions by default.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have added the extension, still the problem remains same. Could anyone  please help me!!!